# How to evaluate data return boolean from jQuery $.get

Tags: php, jquery

```
$('#my_theme').click
(
    function() 
    {
    $('#my_theme option').each(function(){
    //how do I test for this $.get to return true?
        if ($.get('<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/getStyle.php', {template: $(this).val()})==true)
            {
                $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
            }
    });

    }
);


<?php
//getStyle.php

$myTemplate = $_REQUEST['template'];

$file = "styles/".$myTemplate."/style.css";
    if (file_exists($file))
    {
    return true;
    }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript and a server-side language can only communicate using *text*. A simply boolean `true` or `false` can't be sent, you can only send them as `'0'` or `'1'` or whatever other value. Furthermore, `return` doesn't *output* anything, so your Javascript only receives an empty string back, which evaluates to `false`. You'll need to send some specific *string*, or better yet JSON:

```
// PHP
echo json_encode(file_exists($file));

// Javascript
$.getJSON(…)
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

If you're code returns a response like:

```
// more code here
$Response = array('Success' => true);
echo json_encode($Response);
```

Then in your JS you can do like:

```
$.get('<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/getStyle.php', 
        {template: $(this).val()}, function(response) 
{
   if (response.Success)
      $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");

}, "json");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //php
 $res = new StdClass();
 $res->Success = (file_exists($file));
 json_encode($res);

 // jquery
 var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"Success": true}');
 alert( obj.Success === true );
```